# Looping through multidimensional array in PHP, not working

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array from a service, but the normal `foreach` didn't work.  Here is my code:

```
Array
(
    [record] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Jhon
                    [direction] => street 1
                    [last_name] => ops

                )

            ...

        )

)
```

and my loop is

```
 foreach ($array as $key) {
        echo "<h1>".$key["name"]."</h1>";
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($key);
   }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiple `foreach`

```
//echo '<pre>';
foreach ( $array as $records ) {
    foreach ($records as $record ) {
        foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
            printf( '%10s: %s', $key, $value );
        }
    }
}
//echo '</pre>';
```

**Example 1**

```
$record = [ 'name'=>'Jhon', 'direction'=>'street 1', 'last_name'=>'ops' ];
$records['record'] = $record;
$array[] = $records;


//echo '<pre>';

//print_r( $array );

foreach ( $array as $records ) {
    foreach ($records as $record ) {
        foreach ($record as $key => $value) {
            printf( '%10s: %s%s', $key, $value, PHP_EOL );
        }
    }
}
//echo '</pre>';
```

**Example 2**

```
$record = [ 'name'=>'Jhon', 'direction'=>'street 1', 'last_name'=>'ops' ];
$records['record'] = $record;
$array[] = $records;


foreach ( $array as $records ) {
    foreach ($records as $record ) {
        echo 'Name: '. $record['name'] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, look if i used the example 2, show: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Customer as array in

Comment: Just change the name of variables into something else.

Comment: ok, perfect, but its fanny just show the first record, you know why?